# How to Collapse / Expand a Bootstrap Collapse programmatically?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
Lorem ipsum dolor text....
</div>
```

For example imagine this is in **app.component.html** in the Angular project.

There is a variable called showMenu in **app.component.ts**

```
let showMenu: boolean;
```

I want the above div to collapse when showMenu is false and expand when showMenu is true.

Is this possible?

Comment: Try using click event biding and ngIf

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ngClass like shown below to achieve the desired effect.

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse" [ngClass]="{'show': showMenu}">
    Lorem ipsum dolor text....
</div>
```

The collapse is actually adding/removing the '`show`' class internally to hide/show the element. You can do the same using angular like above.

Comment: Perfect. No jQuery required.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your best bet is to swap the `showMenu` variable with a function that you can call when you change the value.
I realize that may not be ideal so your other option is to implement `ngOnChanges()` like so:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  if (this.showMenu) {
    $('#demo').collapse('show');
  } else {
    $('#demo').collapse('hide');
  }
}
```

Remember to import and add ngOnChanges to your class too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the same answer I got to this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
   $('#demo').collapse('toggle');
}
```

Enjoy!